# Start Sonicwall netextender from .Net application

Tags: c#, vpn

The project I am working on requires that I call SonicWall Netextender from a .Net C# application. I have looked at the support documents and searched it online but not able to find any way. I was thinking that it might be possible to call the NEGui.exe from command prompt using necessary arguments but it appears it is possible to do so in SonicWall VPN client but not in Netextender; [Login into SonicWALL VPN through a .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731029/login-into-sonicwall-vpn-through-a-net-application)

Has anybody tried to do this before? Even help with few ideas of how I could approach is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for the command line parameters and my colleague helped me with that. the batch file to connect to the server would look like:

```
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender\
NECLI connect -s IPADDRESS -d DOMAINNAME -u USERNAME-p PASSWORD
```

use "NECLI disconnect" to disconnect the data.